# Session error in Java

Tags: java, session, web

I have this method :

```
public void delete(Class c, int id) throws SQLException {        
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Object ob = this.getById(c, id);
        session.delete(ob);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        throw new SQLException(c.getName() + " - Não foi possivel excluir o registro!");
    }
}
```

and this other:

```
public Object getById(Class c, Integer id) {
    Object session =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(c, id);
    return session;
}
```

This exception is returned :
**Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions**

What is my error ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

**Moreover use finally to close the session:**

```
try{ 
    ...
} catch(HibernateException e){ 
    tx.rollback();
    throw new SQLException(c.getName() + " - Não foi possivel excluir o registro!");
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```